# it is possible Sort Order with f:selectItems (OrderBy)?

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

I work with JSF 2.2 and primefaces7

I want to sort by order my **itemLabel** (ascending or descending) of  the list **usersController.itemsAvailableSelectOne**.

my code :

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="username" value="#{authoritiesController.selected.username}" required="true" >
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.SelectOneMessage}" itemValue="" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{usersController.itemsAvailableSelectOne}"
                   var="usernameItem"
                   itemValue="#{usernameItem}" itemLabel="#{usernameItem.username}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

but i can't find attribute if exist for that !?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not supported by selectOneMenu. Simply sort the `usersController.itemsAvailableSelectOne` collection in your backing bean accordingly.